# Mapping functions over multiple lists

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I am not sure if this is a duplicate. Spent some time looking over list-manip questions.

I’d like to know the Quickest Way to achieve the following Mapping of a function over multiple lists.

Suppose we have multiple lists of unequal length:

```
l1 = {a, b, c, d};
l2 = {x, y, z};
l3 = {u, v};
```

**Q1 What is the quickest way to generate another list as follows (where f is a function):**

```
{{f[a, x, u], f[b, x, u], f[c, x, u], f[d, x, u]},
{f[a, y, u], f[b, y, u], f[c, y, u], f[d, y, u]},
...
{f[a, z, v], f[b, z, v], f[c, z, v], f[d, z, v]}}
```

Now suppose you have a list of functions:

```
{f,g,h,i}
```

**Q2 What is the quickest way to generate a list as follows:**

```
{{f[a, x, u], g[b, x, u], h[c, x, u], i[d, x, u]},
{f[a, y, u], g[b, y, u], h[c, y, u], i[d, y, u]},
...
{f[a, z, v], g[b, z, v], h[c, z, v], i[d, z, v]}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
l1 = {a, b, c, d};
l2 = {x, y, z};
l3 = {u, v};
fns = {f, g, h, i};

expr = Outer[f, l1, l2, l3] ~Flatten~ {3, 2}
```

> ```
> {{f[a, x, u], f[b, x, u], f[c, x, u], f[d, x, u]},
>  {f[a, y, u], f[b, y, u], f[c, y, u], f[d, y, u]},
>  {f[a, z, u], f[b, z, u], f[c, z, u], f[d, z, u]},
>  {f[a, x, v], f[b, x, v], f[c, x, v], f[d, x, v]},
>  {f[a, y, v], f[b, y, v], f[c, y, v], f[d, y, v]},
>  {f[a, z, v], f[b, z, v], f[c, z, v], f[d, z, v]}}
> ```

```
expr[[All, All, 0]] = fns;
expr
```

> ```
> {{f[a, x, u], g[b, x, u], h[c, x, u], i[d, x, u]},
>  {f[a, y, u], g[b, y, u], h[c, y, u], i[d, y, u]},
>  {f[a, z, u], g[b, z, u], h[c, z, u], i[d, z, u]},
>  {f[a, x, v], g[b, x, v], h[c, x, v], i[d, x, v]},
>  {f[a, y, v], g[b, y, v], h[c, y, v], i[d, y, v]},
>  {f[a, z, v], g[b, z, v], h[c, z, v], i[d, z, v]}}
> ```

For creation of the second array directly, without creating the first, use `List` in place of `f` in `Outer` for best performance.

A single performance comparison with István's code, for the second array only:

```
l1 = RandomInteger[999, 150];
l2 = RandomInteger[999, 100];
l3 = RandomInteger[999, 70];
fns = Array[a, 150];

(expr = Outer[List, l1, l2, l3] ~Flatten~ {3, 2}; expr[[All, All, 0]] = fns; 
   expr) // Timing // First

MapThread[Apply, {fns, #}] & /@ 
   Flatten[Transpose[Outer[List, l1, l2, l3], {3, 2, 1}], 1] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.297
>
> 0.764
> ```

Comment: Nice use of zero `Part` index.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Thanks.  Are you the one who introduced that here?  Sadly I cannot remember and I couldn't find the original but I wanted to give credit.

Comment: I have no idea if I was the first. I know in early days here I noted that you could change `Head` that way rather than use `Apply`. Didn't mention this looking for credit -- just thought it was a good use of the zero index (I tend to typically go to `Part` before other functions)

Comment: @Mike Then yes, I think you were the one I learned it from.  I know you weren't seeking credit but I can give it nevertheless. :-)  (If you can recall or find that first post let me know.)  I understand that it is nice to see people using a method that one proposed.

Answer (score 3):

```
l1 = {a, b, c, d};
l2 = {x, y, z};
l3 = {u, v};
fun = {f, g, h, i};

MapThread[Apply, {fun, #}] & /@
   Flatten[Transpose[Outer[List, l1, l2, l3], {3, 2, 1}], 1]
```

> ```
> {{f[a, x, u], g[b, x, u], h[c, x, u], i[d, x, u]},
>  {f[a, y, u], g[b, y, u], h[c, y, u], i[d, y, u]},
>  {f[a, z, u], g[b, z, u], h[c, z, u], i[d, z, u]},
>  {f[a, x, v], g[b, x, v], h[c, x, v], i[d, x, v]},
>  {f[a, y, v], g[b, y, v], h[c, y, v], i[d, y, v]},
>  {f[a, z, v], g[b, z, v], h[c, z, v], i[d, z, v]}}
> ```

Comment: Nuts, you beat me!  I think mine may perform better though.  Testing to follow...

Comment: It does appear that my method is at least somewhat faster, but yours is good too. +1

Comment: Mr W does appear to be slightly faster.  0.000054 vs 0.000087 for the other solution.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Once in a millenium I have that luck :) Nice touch `Set`ting the heads!